# I need some advice to come up with a network plan, or sort of anyway

Tags: networking, router, voip

At my workplace we have been allotted a few IP addresses by the ISP. I think currently one IP is accessible from the outside (by accessible I mean in a browser). Typing this IP into a browser gets you access to a website for employees/customers and this IP is currently assigned to a router we are using.

But, we want our VoIP server (sipXecs) to be accessible outside as well. Currently, external VoIP phones can access the server, but the sipXecs configuration site cannot be accessed outside. We want to assign sipXecs its own IP, and I need to figure out how.

Right now I think all the computers in the office are connected to a switch, and a router is as well. The router (just a standard Linksys) handles the network work. There is a whole bunch of stuff and messy wiring in the server room, but I lack the technical knowledge to tell you more I am afraid.

Currently, we think that the best way to get the sipXecs accessible outside is to buy a second router, assign this second router the other IP, and connect all of our VoIP phones to it.

Is that the best way to do it? Is there anything in particular I should be vary of? Any security measures that I should take? On that same regard, how easy is it for someone evil to access the network devices on an internal server. Like for example, we have an ATA box in the office, connected to the router, and with a local IP assigned by the router, how easy would it be for someone sneaky to access the configuration site of this ATA outside the network?

Answer (score 6):

You really should hire a reputable network professional to help you. You don't need a second router, although you may need a *better* router than the one you currently have. I'd say that you're asking good questions but lack a lot of basic networking know-how, and simply need a seasoned hand to do this for you. In the contract, include some hours for knowledge transfer so that you will be able to do more of this on your own the next time.

This question is really too broad to easily answer (for free, anyway) on this site.

FYI however : this type of question is entirely within the intent of this site. It's not just servers, it's whatever a professional sysadmin has to get his hands dirty with. From the FAQ:

> Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support
>   professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a
>   professional capacity. If your question is about …
>
> ```
> Servers
> Networks
> Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace
> ```

Comment: He could probably even get the ISP to help him out with this.  Depends on the ISP of course, but they should have some sort of high-level technical support available.

Comment: That's entirely possible - although if it's the local ILEC and he's only got a T1, good luck (IME.)

Comment: Haha, Oh my, how should I respond to such polite criticism. 
Thanks for the nice, well thought out answer, I doubt my boss would be willing to hire a professional, especially since my boss was probably the one who set up the network in the first place, so with some research, he could probably see this task through, he probably just wanted me to learn a bit and do some work. 
So, routers can have multiple static ip's assigned to them? I didn't know that, how interesting. 
Also, thanks for the FYI, I will be sure to bug you guys a lot more now.

Comment: I didn't say that you would assign extra IPs to the router. You could do that and NAT everything, or you could make a DMZ, and/or you could dual-home the device. Why, exactly, do you want to expose the web interface of your VoIP server to the public internet?